# How do I ensure all calls are returned and pushed into the array before passing the action to the reducers?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, redux, react-redux

I have an ActionCreator that makes an API call to Google Places for each place_id. I then want to push the response into an array, which I then pass over to my reducer. The problem is I'm dispatching the array before it even has a chance to get filled up. How do I go about working through this problem?

```
export function placesFetchBookmarks(place_ids) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const newPlaces = [];
    place_ids.forEach(place_id => {
      const request = { placeId: place_id };
      const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
      service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          newPlaces.push(place);
        } else {
          dispatch(placeDetailsHasErrored(true));
        }
      });
    });
    dispatch({
      type: PLACES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
      places: newPlaces
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` and have your asynchronous calls resolve promises instead. Something like this should work:

```
const promises = place_ids.map(place_id => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = { placeId: place_id };
        const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
        service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                resolve(place);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(places => dispatch({
      type: PLACES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
      places
    }))
    .catch(() => dispatch(placeDetailsHasErrored(true)))
```